# Google library Base64.decodeBase64 no such method

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, backend, google-signin

Given spring boot, Kotlin 1,6, Java 11.
When I try to verify google IdToken, it calls `Base64.decodeBase64` inside `JsonWebSignature` class of `google-http-client` library. Library version 1.42.2 (Latest), also tried 1.28 as it says that bug was fixed there and apache dependency of base64 was removed.

Questions is: is there any working solution (this was taken from google official docs), workarounds or other 3rd part libraries to implement verification and reading payload out of token received from client side via google sign in?

Comment: @JoopEggen how can I say imported third party library which Base64 should be used?

Comment: Sorry I did not pay attention. Base64 was implemented several times, and then came java.util.Base64. You must still have some dependency taking an old library, despite that "latest." In a _maven_ project you could dump the dependency tree. You might need to look in all the jars you are using.

Comment: @PavelSarpov could you please paste the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: This issue is probably due a dependency conflict - some other library you are using imports an older version of the aforementioned `google-http-client` library that takes precedence in the CP. Are you using gradle of maven?

Comment: @Sheinbergon it is a maven. I do not know how to see what other libraries also implement/include Base64 class